# RiscV swap instruction wouldn't be possible in single-cycle CPU because it would write two registers?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv

My lecturer said we can't implement the following command in RiscV processor single cycle:

```
swap rA, rB
```

which swaps the values between register rA and register rB. His explanation was that in such command we need to write to register file twice which isn't possible.

But why is that?

We can always ask the register file to write twice, what's the problem with that?

[image]

Comment: You answered your own question, it takes one clock per write, which is two clocks.  Two clocks is > one clock, you cannot do two clocks worth of things in one clock.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it you just cannot do it in one clock. "single cycle" means single clock cycle.

Comment: If you dont use a register file and each register is its own latch or set of flip flops then you could write two things in one cycle, yes.  There is a reason that register files are used, both between the overall logic used, the physical size of the processor (which leads to yield/cost, power, etc) and the length of the logic path and as a result how fast the processor can run.

Comment: At the same time you have a similar issue with add x10,x11,x12  you need to do two register file reads and one write which takes two clocks minimum.  The swap has the same issue two reads, two writes takes three clocks minimum.  So definition of "single cycle" is the key here.

Comment: Can you architect a multi-ported sram?  Yes, of course you can and you could use one of those in this use case to allow for multiple reads and multiple writes in one clock cycle.  But you are back into the size of the thing and the overall cost.   The whole point of pipelines is to take things that take a few to many steps and average them out to one clock per instruction when the pipeline is working at its most efficient (no branches,  no memory accesses, etc).

Comment: you can easily implement a swap in risc-v...just design your pipe for it...but a typical register file you cannot read two things at a time nor write, you can maybe read and write in one cycle so you would need either 3 or 4 clocks just for the register file access for a swap (you can maybe share one in another pipe stage, like read during decode).

Comment: @old_timer then how can we use save to memory and save to register in one clock as in lw command?

Comment: The text you're quoting says it is possible only with "RegisterFile structure changes".  Those changes would be adding a 2nd write port to the RegisterFile.  It is only not possible without that 2nd write port.  A 2nd write port costs hardware, but if you want to pay that price then this is possible.

Comment: @john those are separate srams so no problem, you can do those in parallel, although load word does not write to memory it reads from memory.

Comment: reading or writing memory (external to the core, not register file or other srams) is expected to take a few to hundreds of clock cycles BTW...single core the processor stalls for this...so it may be one stage in a pipe but multiple to many clocks.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't depend on RISC-V itself in any way but just on particular implementation. The ISA doesn't dictate the implementation details. Well, it suggests some style, and instructions are designed to alleviate hardware implementation the most simple style (a least gates), while still targeting more complex designs. But, how many register writes are allowed in parallel, is just implementation principle.

If you look at RISC-V instruction listing, youʼll see that *nothing* of the base set (IMAFD) directly specifies writing to 2 or more registers at the same time. This is what allows an implementation that has a register file with a single input gate (a data bus connected to ALU, memory reading module, whatever). Some instructions that would have violated this (e.g. putting 64-bit floating value into 2 32-bit registers) are not implemented because of this restriction.

OTOH, in a more complex design, this is possible, and even recommended. The "M" section explicitly states:

> If both the high and low bits of the same product are required, then the recommended code sequence is: MULH[[S]U] rdh, rs1, rs2; MUL rdl, rs1, rs2 (source register specifiers must be in same order and rdh cannot be the same as rs1 or rs2). Microarchitectures can then fuse these into a single multiply operation instead of performing two separate multiplies.

(and similarly for division that produces both quotient and remainder)

If such multiplication or division instructions are fused, as described, into a single operation, it *is* possible (and definitely *will* be used in high-performance targets with OoO, register renaming, etc.) to utilize two-input-gate register file to write both results at the same cycle.

So, the question just pertains the implementation cost.

Notice also that there *is* atomic swap between a general purpose register and a service register (CSR in the spec terminology), and between register and memory. But, CSRs clearly are a separate matter, and, memory access style can be any of tens known.